# PHP - Objects and Arrays - How to access an stdClass object "name" "value" pair inside an array?

Tags: php, arrays, object

I would like to know how to return a value of an object with a name value pair that's inside an array. I've been trying all sorts of methods and frankly I realized I may be way over my head on this. I'd like some assistance trying to get the AirportsInformation_DataExtension value inside the property array.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [OverallStatus] => OK
    [RequestID] => 19e41b46-df68-47ba-8858-d728f3a92036
    [Results] => stdClass Object
        (
            [PartnerKey] => 
            [ObjectID] => 
            [Type] => DataExtensionObject
            [Properties] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Property] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [Name] => CampaignName
                                    [Value] => 20130107_FlightDealsHotelPricePoints
                                )

                            [1] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [Name] => StartDate
                                    [Value] => 1/7/2013 12:00:00 AM
                                )

                            [2] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [Name] => EndDate
                                    [Value] => 1/15/2013 5:59:59 AM
                                )

                            [3] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [Name] => CampaignType
                                    [Value] => FlightDeals
                                )

                            [4] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [Name] => LandingPage_ExpireDate
                                    [Value] => 1/15/2013 5:59:59 AM
                                )

                            [5] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [Name] => LandingPage_AutoRedirectOnExpire
                                    [Value] => True
                                )

                            [6] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [Name] => LandingPage_ExpireTargetURL
                                    [Value] => test
                                )

                            [7] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [Name] => BookByDate
                                    [Value] => 1/22/2013 12:00:00 AM
                                )

                            [8] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [Name] => TravelStartDate
                                    [Value] => 
                                )

                            [9] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [Name] => TravelEndDate
                                    [Value] => 
                                )

                            [10] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [Name] => FlightDeals_DataExtension
                                    [Value] => 20130107_DestinationFlightDeals
                                )

                            [11] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [Name] => FlightDeals_SortOrder_DataExtension
                                    [Value] => FlightDeals_DestinationSortOrder
                                )

                            [12] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [Name] => HotelDeals_DataExtension
                                    [Value] => 20130107_FlightDealsHotelPricePoints
                                )

                            [13] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [Name] => HotelDeals_All_DataExtension
                                    [Value] => 20130107_HotelPackageDeals_ALL
                                )

                            [14] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [Name] => HotelInformation_DataExtension
                                    [Value] => EmailHotelInformation
                                )

                            [15] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [Name] => AirportsInformation_DataExtension
                                    [Value] => Airports
                                )

                            [16] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [Name] => RoutesInformation_DataExtension
                                    [Value] => Routes
                                )

                            [17] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [Name] => DFP_DataExtension
                                    [Value] => ET_DestinationIframeSrc
                                )

                            [18] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [Name] => DeepLinkConnectorURL
                                    [Value] => http://www.somewebsite/BookingConnector.html?mode=run
                                )

                            [19] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [Name] => DefaultDestinationScenery
                                    [Value] => LAS
                                )

                            [20] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [Name] => DefaultHomeAirportCode
                                    [Value] => 
                                )

                            [21] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [Name] => FailSafeHomeAiportCode
                                    [Value] => 
                                )

                            [22] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [Name] => DFP_Campaign_Banner
                                    [Value] => True
                                )

                            [23] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [Name] => EmailID
                                    [Value] => 44388
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Using a foreach loop I was able to print out all lines with name/value sets

```
foreach ($results->Results->Properties->Property as $CurrentProp){
    print('<br>');
    print('Name: '.$CurrentProp->Name. ' Value: '.$CurrentProp->Value.'<br>');                    
};
```

Sadly I can't get passed that. I just need to retrieve the value. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the `$results` is that object you outputted above, then your code should work. What error are you getting (assuming you have error reporting on).

Comment: Hi Glavic, with the foreach loop there was no error generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would need to be able to get all the values based on their name, it could be useful to turn it in to an associative array, like this

```
$results->Results->Properties->PropertyArray = array();
foreach($results->Results->Properties->Property as $arrCurrentProperty) {
  $results->Results->Properties->PropertyArray[$arrCurrentProperty->Name] = $arrCurrentProperty->Value;
};
```

Then you can get the values later by indexing them directly, i.e.

```
echo 'The value is: ' . $results->Results->Properties->PropertyArray['AirportsInformation_DataExtension'];
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to get the value, you could loop over them and test for the name matching `AirportsInformation_DataExtension`:

```
foreach ($results->Results->Properties->Property as $CurrentProp){

    if($CurrentProp->Name == 'AirportsInformation_DataExtension')
    {
        echo 'The value is: ' . $CurrentProp->Value;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the above [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14354861/559221) by MrCode or, simply just use `$results->Results->Properties->Property[15]->Value` if the index of `AirportsInformation_DataExtension` is always `15`. Since an array is an `ordered` list, it is very probably that the index does not change unless some of the items are removed/added from the array/

Comment: Hi @Sparky, this also works beautifully. There's low chance that the index will change. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($results->Results->Properties->Property as $CurrentProp){
    $tempArr[$CurrentProp->Name] = $CurrentProp->Value;
}

echo $tempArr['AirportsInformation_DataExtension'];
```

By this you can access any other key of that object.